# Create undecorated function in Borland C

Tags: c, turbo-c

```
void empty() { }
```

will be compiled to

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
ret
```

How do I declare the function so that it has no "decoration" code? just plain `ret`.
If that is not possible, is this possible to define completely assembler function inside the `.C` file? It is possible to define assembler function in the `.asm` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the function with the [`__declspec(naked)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Declspec%28naked%29) modifier.